# JavaScript, Função que agrupa strings de acordo com valor do parâmetro

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando resolver o exercício que consta na imagem, a linguagem e' javascript:

[image]

eis o código que criei, porem so funciona para alguns casos e nao para o do exemplo dado (pp) por exemplo, alguém poderia me ajudar a escreve-lo mais elegantemente utilizando das ferramentas JS?

```
function test(line_size){
    return function(text){
        let word ="";
        let result =[];
        let array = text.split(/\s+/);
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(word.length + array[i].length + 1 <= line_size){
                if(word.length === 0){
                    word += array[i];
                }else{
                    word += " " + array[i];
                }
            }else{
                result.push(word);
                word = array[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

pp = test(8);
pp('aaa bbb ccc')

console.log(pp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vão aparecer códigos melhores, aqui vai minha pequena e humilde sugestão:

```js
function test(line_size){
    return function(text){
        if (!text) {
          return [];
        }
        let remainingText = text;
        const result = [];
        while (remainingText.length > 0) {
            const splittedText = (remainingText.length >= line_size) ? remainingText.slice(0,line_size) : remainingText;
            remainingText = remainingText.slice(line_size);
            result.push(splittedText);
        }
        return result;
    }
}


pp = test(8);
result1 = pp('aaa bbb ccc');
result2 = pp('xxxx yy zzzz w');

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Impressionante, eu demoro muito para chegar numa solução pros problemas, geralmente começo no papel e depois tento escrever no computador a ideia que tive, se vc nao se importa deu perguntar, como eh o seu processo de pensar na solução ate a hora de escrever o código? E muito obrigado pela correção, vou estudar o que voce me passou

Comment: É apenas prática, você faz de uma forma hoje, vê uma pessoa fazendo de outra e aprende, depois de outra, e sempre se atualizando. Aqui pessoas com mais tempo de experiência que eu fazem códigos ainda melhores, na sua grande maioria.

Comment: 'e verdade, ler o seu código me deu muita noção nova. Muito Obrigado. Tava testando com outras strings e parece que ele nao funciona pra algumas palavras muito pequenas, por exemplo se usar pp = test(20) result3 = pp("dhokgqcoxz  ftinckwt cwdyyn  rjobtezm   zitsjnprri hcdbshpsy  ybkzbjtco  oyzyihyhboxu kjqqrggm sxtxscr fgdsqqpmotz   ohnlzakiw lpyredgaml smpbttbcumj znqrqp rezdtz qojyextfvvne  rbcbv qwhtydxgi.  ") as palavras menores Dao problema

Comment: Eu li seu exercício com mais atenção desta vez e vi que tem alguns requisitos especiais. Você vai ter de implementar algumas regras ai pra funcionar direitinho.

Answer (score 0):

Eu cheguei neste código. Com os exemplos que você deu, parece que está ok. Teria que fazer outros testes pra ver se atende todos os requisitos do exercício...

```js
function mkPretty(line_size) {

  return function(string) {
    const arr = string.replace(/\s{2,}/gm,' ').trim().split('');
    const result = [];
    while (arr.length) {
      result.push(arr.splice(0,line_size || 72).join('').trim());
    }
    return result;
  }

}

let pp = mkPretty(8);

console.log(pp('aaa bbb ccc'));
console.log(pp('aaa      bbb       ccc'));
console.log(pp('xxxx yy zzzz w'));

pp = mkPretty(20);

console.log(pp('dhokgqcoxz ftinckwt cwdyyn rjobtezm zitsjnprri hcdbshpsy ybkzbjtco oyzyihyhboxu kjqqrggm sxtxscr fgdsqqpmotz ohnlzakiw lpyredgaml smpbttbcumj znqrqp rezdtz qojyextfvvne rbcbv qwhtydxgi.'));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente, e esse código 'e super compacto, porem não entendi muito bem algumas passadas, se voce nao se importar em me explicar: nessa parte, o que o replace esta fazendo? .replace(/\s{2,}/gm,' ')

Comment: achei um caso que o código parece nao dar a resposta esperada: pp=mkPretty(20)pp("ilfetaoio  lgnzievconz  ivhsxwk  kqaaniqj\neey jsqigfw  wcckudxbpov
scneshx esnzfejxu spbf
jlnlvhpbmv
fhkf  cqmzboxfs  wguyedikkjn.  ")